# How to create a popover which shows some value from back-end, and the popover has to display on mouse-over a label in c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Is it Possible to do this in a simple way?

Can anybody answer please.....!

> This is the code for label, on mouse over, the pop-over has to show

```
<asp:Label ID="lblAuditInfo" runat="server" Text="Audit Info"></asp:Label>
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Javascript library to render the popovers, e.g. [qtip2](http://qtip2.com/). Instead of providing the content text directly, you can load it using AJAX. Here I use jQuery for the AJAX call.

```
function registerTooltip_(element) {
    // load tooltip content from backend ...
    var loadContent = function () {
        return $.ajax({
            url: 'http://backend.com/tooltip',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { id: element.id }, // provide parameters for backend here!
        })
        .done(function (html) { // backend returns tooltip text or HTML markup
            return html;
        });
    };

    element.qtip({
        content: {
            text: loadContent
        },
        show: 'mouseenter',
        hide: 'unfocus mouseleave', // Unfocus = click anywhere but tooltip & target
    });
}
```